# What Typo3 newsletter extension can automatically fetch web content changes

Tags: typo3, newsletter

The Typo3 extension tt_news enables for example all created news by this extension to be shown in the newsletter but not content from a "not news" page of the website.

We are looking for a plugin which automatically finds new content on the website and let us create a newsletter from it.

What extension could be used here? Might direct mail be able to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Direct Mail manual: "Newsletter pages are just normal pages. Their rendering is configured by the TS template."

A very simple solution for what you want to do would be to write a simple extension where you get the newest content elements and output them. Direct Mail itself will not do that for you, but it will send out any content that you provide on the "Newsletter page".